# android setBackground animation

Tags: android, android-animation

Currently I set background of a LinearLayout using

```
BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), mBlurredMap);
mLytProfileCover.setBackground(bd);
```

How can I animation this? For example, a fade-in animation where the background's alpha changes from 0 to 1 in 500ms.

Thanks.

Comment: Nice question because everything in Android seems too static for me. And if you use CustomViews, many things arise...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ObjectAnimator alphaAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mLytProfileCover, View.ALPHA, 0.0f, 1.0f);
alphaAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(final Animator animation) {
        mLytProfileCover.setBackground(bd);
    }
});
alphaAnimator.setDuration(500);
alphaAnimator.start();
```

Comment: this changes the whole LinearLayout visibility from 0 to 1. I am looking for a way that only changes its background, not the content within the linear layout.

Comment: @windchimez have a `View` as a first child of your layout. Set the background to that `View`, and animate it, not the layout.